# Python. Что такое self, наследование и с чем их едят?

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter, наследование

Что же такое self, как работает передача определенных значений переменных между функциями и как это все между собой работает?

Дело в том, что я задался целью написать небольшую текстовую RPG игру, в целях преодоления на своем пути определенного ряда трудностей и расширения своих знаний касательно ООП. Набросав небольшой макет действий, я принялся к его реализации. Использовать я решил библиотеку tkinter, в целях отрисовки графической составляющей игры и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

При попытке запуска моего кода, я столкнулся с ошибкой, что будет описана под ним.

```
Main.py
-------
from tkinter import *
from Constants import *

class Main():

    def __init__(self):
        # Отрисовка окна и его параметры
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Hero dash')
        self.root.geometry(geometry_size)
        self.running = True
        self.root.resizable(False,False)

    def render(self):
        root.configure(background='#f23f23')

    def main_loop(self):
        # Основной цикл игры
        while self.running == True:
            root.render()
            root.mainloop()
Main.main_loop()    
---------------------------
Constants.py
------------
geometry_size = '800x600+250+40'
```

А вот и код ошибки.

```
TypeError: main_loop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Как я понял, беда в нехватке аргументов, которые я передаю в функцию, при попытке её вызова. Но у меня возник вопрос, а что же вообще такое эта 'self' и для чего она используется, какие значения может принимать и каким образом я могу воспользоваться root в других функциях? Имеется в виду, как её значение "внедрить" в другую функцию?

Comment: `self` в качестве первого аргумента методов — текущий экземпляр класса (объект), а вы никаких экземпляров не создали. Вы просто вызываете функцию в классе напрямую без каких-либо экземпляров — вот в `self` ничего и не передаётся. Код `Main().main_loop()` — будет работать

Comment: Ну, точнее, не совсем работать — вам нужно будет ещё заменить `root` на `self.root`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `self` представляет собой экземпляр самого объекта. Другими словами,  ссылка на текущий экземпляр данного класса (в данном случае это класс `Main` который наследует класс `Tk`).

Один из вариантов кода вашей программы:

```
from tkinter import Tk


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Отрисовка окна и его параметры
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Hero dash')
        self.running = True
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        self.configure(background='#f23f23')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: "ссылка класса на самого себя" - не лучший способ сделать понятней. Ссылка на текущий экземпляр данного класса (объект) - может так лучше.